# data published by JavaScript (ajax json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

hi everyone I have two different code for Ajax and I'm going to mix them both together, but I could not Mix I was so ridiculous I know, but I try myself please help me i am novice ...

I want to turn to the array to json And the data published by JavaScript

js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $orders = $('#orders');
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'server.php',
    success : function(data){
         $.each(orders, function(i , data){
         $orders.append('<li>name: ' + data.name + 'family: ' + data.family + '</li>');
    },
});


});
```

php

```
<?php 

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM myfeilds');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();

$namesArray = array();
foreach ($results as $row) {
    array_push($namesArray, $row);
}

echo json_encode($namesArray);

?>
```

Comment: you forgot to parse it, use `jQuery.parseJSON( /*your json*/ )`. Reference :  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: you forgot to send the json header in your php

Comment: why are you using ajax if you are triggering it when the page is loaded ?

Comment: You have a syntax error within your JS. You forgot to end the statement for `$.each`. :))  Use the console in the dev tools to check for different errors in your code. Press 12 if you're on chrome, then go to the `Console` tab.

Comment: error console is : 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Answer (score 0):

Your `ajax` should look like this. You need to parse the `json_encoded` data using `JSON.parse`.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'server.php',
  success: function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    $.each(orders, function(i, data) {
      $orders.append('<li>name: ' + data.name + 'family: ' + data.family + '</li>');
    });
  }
});
```